# How can I write an sql query for the following scenario?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am writing this query for report viewer :

```
SELECT        Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM            Customer_New
WHERE        (Clients_Title = @Clients_Title) OR
                         (Address_Current = @Address_Current) OR
                         (Phone_Number = @Phone_Number) OR
                         (Mobile_Number = @Mobile_Number) OR
                         (AreaLocation = @AreaLocation)
```

What I want is:

- When there are no parameter that is provided to the report viewer, all of the customer record will be displayed.
- If there are parameters provided, the `OR` condition is implemented .
- Lastly, if there is contrast in any where condition, then no record will be displayed.

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: is this mysql or tsql? Tt is hard to imagine it is both

Comment: i have mentioned it in title it is sql ..

Comment: it is both tsql and mysql? LOL

Comment: sorry for mistake .Thank for correction .

Comment: You have asked this same question 4 times on SO in a week. Please delete the extraneous questions and edit which one you want to keep active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is :

```
SELECT        Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
    FROM            Customer_New
        where        (CASE
            WHEN @Clients_Title != ''   THEN Clients_Title=@Clients_Title
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
          AND(CASE
            WHEN @Address_Current != '' THEN Address_Current =@Address_Current
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
                  AND(CASE
            WHEN @Phone_Number != '' THEN Phone_Number=@Phone_Number
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
          AND(CASE
            WHEN @Mobile_Number != '' THEN Mobile_Number=@Mobile_Number
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
          AND(CASE
            WHEN @AreaLocation != '' THEN AreaLocation =@AreaLocation
          ELSE
             NULL IS NULL
          END)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM Customer_New
WHERE (Clients_Title = @Clients_Title   OR @Clients_Title IS NULL)
AND (Address_Current  = @Address_Current OR @Address_Current IS NULL) 
AND (Phone_Number     = @Phone_Number    OR @Phone_Number IS NULL) 
AND (Mobile_Number    = @Mobile_Number   OR @Mobile_Number IS NULL) 
AND (AreaLocation     = @AreaLocation    OR @AreaLocation  IS NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry it is not giving desired result ...It is not full filling none of the above condition that i mentioned